# How do I select tags ending on a specific string?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am getting started with Web Components and want to get all elements where the tag name ends in "-component", in order to register them as custom tags.

For best performance, I want to use querySelectorAll **and not iterate over all elements**.

However, as you can see in the following example `[tag$="-component"]` does not find the elements.

```js
const components = document.querySelectorAll('[tag$="-component"]');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

result.innerHTML = 'Search started<br>';

for(var i = 0; i < components.length; i++){
 
  result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + components[i].tagName + '<br>';
 
}
```

```html
<my-component>

  <hello-world-component>
  
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  
  </hello-world-component>

</my-component>

<div class="result"></div>
```

If anyone knows what is going on and could let me know or if anyone knows if this is even possible it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS syntax `$=` applies to element *attributes*, not to elements themselves.

There is no syntax to create a CSS selector that matches elements that have a certain suffix.

However, if the purpose is to find custom elements that have not been registered yet, you can use the `:defined` selector:

```js
const components = document.querySelectorAll(':not(:defined)');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

result.innerHTML = 'Search started<br>';

for(var i = 0; i < components.length; i++){
  result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + components[i].tagName + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<my-component>
  <hello-world-component>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </hello-world-component>
</my-component>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! You that is really unfortunate, but I had a suspicion that might be the case.

Comment: But I have a solution for you. See addition to answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "tag" attribute defined in those elements. But you can add it via javascript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(":where(my-component, my-component *)")
  .forEach(c => c.setAttribute("tag", c.tagName.toLowerCase()));

const components = document.querySelectorAll('[tag$="-component"]');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

result.innerHTML = 'Search started<br>';

for(var i = 0; i < components.length; i++){
 
  result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + components[i].tagName + '<br>';
 
}
```

```html
<my-component>

  <hello-world-component>
  
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  
  </hello-world-component>

</my-component>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a way to use the `$=` syntax to work on tags, not the attributes, but I am guessing what I am trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

##### **No** need for *Global* script or `:defined`

- Make the component set its own `tag` **attribute**

  - all CSS will be correctly applied
  - all `querySelectorAll` will work

```js
customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    this.setAttribute("tag", this.localName);
  }
});

document.body.append( 
                     document.querySelectorAll('[tag$="-component"]').length , 
                     " Components!" 
                    );
```

```css
/* get all Nodes with the tag attribute *ending* on -component */
[tag$="-component"] {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<my-component>Component 1</my-component>
<my-component>Component 2</my-component>
<my-component>Component 3</my-component>
<my-component>Component 4</my-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad structure to work with. Encountering such a problem means you're not using the tags as they were expected to be used: I would recommend you **not to go this way**, you shouldn't really find workarounds of picking the tags which end/start/contain a specific string.

The way you're going is

- not providing neither readability of HTML
- nor ads elegance and performance to your JS code
- also makes your CSS more bulky, since you cannot gracefully add common styling to the elements that are expected have something in common

There're no advantages of doing it. There's a reason attributes exist, and it is to provide a way to further classify your tags / components.

Considering that you're also learning to create custom Web Components, this should immediately make you drop an idea of using similar-but-different tags that share some functionality but differ at other. Instead, you should strongly consider using one component to make a single class for them to implement different functionality inside-the-class (or probably extend it).

You have a plenty of ways to go here.

To sum up, below is a **bad practice**:

```
<my-panel-component></my-panel-component>
<my-header-component></my-header-component>
```

*One good practice* is to use class attribute to differentiate, in which case I would recommend having a common prefix for the class so you can easily pick the class among any other classes (and to ensure or be at least almost certain they do not interfere with other classes used in application):

```
<my-component class = "cmp-panel"></my-component>
<my-component class = "cmp-header"></my-component>
```

*Another possible approach* is using custom-defined attributes:

```
<my-component type = "panel"></my-component>
<my-component type = "header"></my-component>
```